# How to add a post tsc build task that copy files?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

How to add another task to VSCode, that copies files from x to y, after the tsc build task?

Comment: Why not specify the `outDir` for your tsc task so no moving of files is required?

Comment: I need the js files in both locations. 1 is under source control, the other is the server.
+ There are other, not ts output files like html/css that needs to be copied

Comment: Mabye a bit of late perhaps. Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Evelie: I moved to gulp as suggested

Comment: An answer using shell commands can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43657839/how-to-chain-tasks-in-visual-studio-code-using-only-tasks-json/50241977#50241977

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a task runner like gulp to accomplish this...

You can configure vscode to run the `build` task below, which is dependent upon the `compile` task.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('build', ['compile'], function () {
  return gulp.src('./config/**/*.json')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

gulp.task('compile', function (done) {
  exec('tsc -p ./app', function (err, stdOut, stdErr) {
    console.log(stdOut);
    if (err){
      done(err);
    } else {
      done();
    }
  });
});
```

There is documentation about running gulp tasks via vscode here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/tasks

Answer (score 26):

You can use `npm scripts` for this. For example my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "compile": "tsc -p . ",
  "html": "cp -r ./src/public/ ./bin/public/",
  "views": "cp -r ./src/views/ ./bin/views/",
  "build": "npm run compile && npm run views && npm run html"
}
```

Here 2 scripts `html` and `views` for copying and task `build` runs them concurrently.
In `tasks.json` I have next:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "npm",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "args": [
                "run",
                "build"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So `shift+cmd+B` will run `npm build` script.

Comment: Works OK as long as you're on a Unix-like environment :)

Comment: you can use Robocopy on windows: "copy:resources": "robocopy src/public bin/public & exit 0" in your package.json scripts, then npm run copy:resources

Comment: `ncp` is a cross platform npm package that works like `cp -r`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're running in some kind of "developer mode" and need to `--watch` for file changes to run a task after every compile, I prefer using [tsc-watch](https://github.com/gilamran/tsc-watch) to accomplish this.

For example, in `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsc-watch --onSuccess=\"yarn otherThing\"",
    "otherThing": "echo \"hi\""
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I manage to do it.

```"scripts": {
    "serve": "npm run compile",
    "compile": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"npm run dev\" --compiler /home/usrname/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/tsc",
    "dev": "nodemon ./dist"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take any script name in package.json and prepend it with 'post' or 'pre'.  So if you want it to run after a script named 'tsc', add a 'posttsc' command in scripts. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts