# How to chain tasks in Visual Studio Code using only tasks.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have been ploughing through the documentation of [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) to figure out how to add multiple consecutive tasks to the `tasks.json` file.

The `tasks` array only allows for creating different arguments to the same command. In this example the command is `echo`.

```json
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "echo",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "showOutput": "always",
    "echoCommand": true,
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "hello",
            "args": ["Hello World"]
        },
        {
            "taskName": "bye",
            "args": ["Good Bye"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Does tasks.json allow several tasks to be executed consecutively? For example, `tsc` followed by `uglify`?

Comment: In the latest version of VS Code I don't use tasks.json at all anymore. You can put your commands under the `scripts` tag in `package.json`. If you only need two or three consecutive commands you can use the `pre` and `post` tags. If your build process becomes more complex you can use gulp or webpack.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `dependsOn` feature was shipped in [version 1.10.0](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_more-work-on-terminal-runner). For example, I am using this to compile and run single file scripts in TypeScript:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "command": "tsc -p ${cwd}/2017-play",
            "label": "tsc-compile",
            "type": "shell"
        },
        {
            "command": "node ${cwd}/2017-play/build/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.js",
            "label": "node-exec",
            "type": "shell",
            "dependsOn": [
                "tsc-compile"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That's a huge improvement! But I still think MS's documentation is incredibly unclear on how to use `tasks.json`. By this point, I've given up and just use `npm scripts` or `webpack`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working example that runs the tcs build and copies the source to another folder using a shell script.
This is based on various posts on StackOverflow and the documentation found here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_more-work-on-terminal-runner

One could also make a tasks.json with two tasks with the second having a dependsOn on the first one as shown in Ben Creasy post, the two tasks would get executed when the second one is called. I needed to be able to execute one, the other or both. Many thanks to Ben, I had a hard time finding a solution before hitting this post.

BTW, when including a shell file, the commands are run with reference to the project folder, not the one where the script is located.

```
{
 // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
 // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
 "version": "2.0.0",
 "tasks": [
  {
   "type": "typescript",
   "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
   "problemMatcher": [
    "$tsc"
   ],
   "group": "build",
   "identifier": "build"
  },
  {
   "label": "Copy files",
   "type": "shell",
   "command": "./scripts/copysrc.sh",
   "windows": {
    "command": ".\\scripts\\copysrc.cmd"
   },
   "group": "build",
   "presentation": {
    "reveal": "always"
   },
   "problemMatcher": [],
   "dependsOn": "build"
  },
  {
   "label": "Build and copy",
   "dependsOn": [
    "build",
    "Copy files"
   ],
   "group": "build",
   "problemMatcher": []
  }
 ]
}
```